# Proper Implementation Of Program Values

Tags: kotlin

Let's say I have a set of program-wide values (think addresses of internal resources, maximum/minimum values, the type of OS using the program, etc). These types of values wouldn't *necessarily* need to be calculated until they're called upon.

**What would be the ideal way to handle theses values?**

For example, the name of the program:

```
object ProgramInfo {
    val programName: String
}
```

I could do:

1. KISS:   `val programName = "The Program"`
2. Lazy:   `val programName by lazy { "The Program" }`
3. Getter: `val programName: String get() = "The Program"`

Option 1 would avoid complexity and instantiation overhead during call time but would load eagerly, taking up memory even if never used. Life cycle is as long as the program.

Option 2 would offload instantiation to call time instead of eagerly, or avoid instantiation completely if never called. However, once called, the cons mirror Option 1.

Option 3 seems like it could offload any life-cycle concerns to the caller. But there could be a problem if there are too many callers at once, essentially making a bunch of copies.

Realistically, this type of distinction may be too minor to have any worthwhile effects. I know there are most likely cases where some cons matter more than others, but I am not sure what to prioritize: lifecycle length, init/getter costs, duplication-related bloating?

**Edit:**

Option 4: `const val programName = "The Program"`

It has the main advantage of being computed during compile time, and I actually am fine with this option when the values are completely non-dynamic. For instance, checking which OS is being used would be something that doesn't change but would require a function call which constants don't allow. After looking [here](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/best-practice-where-to-put-my-class-constants/15395), it seems like constants are mainly about announcing intent anyways, with more dynamic values use option 3. Does that sound right?

Comment: [compile-time-constants](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#compile-time-constants)

Comment: @IR42 Would you mind elaborating through posting and answer? Linking documentation is a good start but it's not much of an answer especially since the documentation doesn't say why to use it, only the conditions in which it is allowed to be used.

Comment: If you want to use the variable only as a read-only variable, you can use the `const` keyword. The advantage is that the value can be computed at compile-time.

Comment: I can see the benefit in that. I will update my question accordingly.

Comment: I can't see that this question is really answerable.  What aspects to prioritise will depend upon the program: on how often the data is used, how costly it is to calculate, how important delays at start-up and/or at first use are, whether multiple threads are active, how tight memory is, &c.  We could only discuss the contrasts between the options — and the question has already done some of that.